# ANDROID: I need to create a static menu at the top of the view (like Create, Edit)

Tags: android

I have a menu for about, exit.
But i need to create another static menu for options.
I will prefer to be at the top of the list that i have.

like:

Create, Edit

List

and when i press the menu button to open the (Exit,About).

If You can help, it will be perfect.
Thank you , have a good day.

Comment: i do not know how to make it, i do not start. i dont know how.

Comment: I have for my menu (i mean when i press menu i get it : the code is this: <@Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
  
  MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
  
  inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
  
  return true;>

Comment: Did you see my answer? It links to a great post that shows you how to create a menu bar at the top of your application.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) post, and [this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) one. The second post has nothing to do with what you want, it's just a nifty way to spruce up your UI by adding a QuickAction. The first post shows you how to build an "ActionBar" for Android.